# Set data in model from multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to set data in a object(User.java) from two activities(StudyProgram.java and LogIn.java) and show it in a single activity(SecondActivity.java) or screen at a runtime but I am facing a problem. My code is showing shared data in single activity but not at a same time or screen. It is showing in two screens respectively. But, I want to show it in same screen which is difficult to me. My code is

Login.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,SecondActivity.class);
user.setName(name);
user.setFacebookId(id);
intent.putExtra("User", user);
startActivity(intent);
```

StudyProgram.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
user.setVuId(data);
user.setStudyProgram(data1);
intent.putExtra("User", user);
startActivity(intent);
```

User.java

```
package com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by MFRajput on 01/05/16.
 */
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String studyProgram;
    private String name;
    private String facebookId;
    private String vuId;

    public User(String studyProgram, String name, String facebookId, String vuId) {
        this.studyProgram = studyProgram;
        this.name = name;
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
        this.vuId = vuId;
    }

    public User() {
       }


    public String getVuId(String data) {
        return vuId;
    }

    public void setVuId(String vuId) {
        this.vuId = vuId;
    }

    public String getStudyProgram(String data1) {
        return studyProgram;
    }

    public void setStudyProgram(String studyProgram) {
        this.studyProgram = studyProgram;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFacebookId() {
        return facebookId;
    }

    public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
        this.facebookId = facebookId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "studyProgram='" + studyProgram + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", facebookId='" + facebookId + '\'' +
                ", vuId='" + vuId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    }
```

SecondActivity.java

```
package com.technerdshub.vusocial.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.technerdshub.vusocial.Models.User;
import com.technerdshub.vusocial.R;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("User");

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(user.toString());
    }
}
```

Please anybody help me, how can I do it?

Comment: not clear to me. what do you want to do exactly here ?

Comment: You could make the User Object a singleton, but it isn't really clear what you are trying to do because the Login activity shouldn't be shown alongside any other activity

Comment: @Shubhank I want to create one object and access all variables in it which i have declared in other activities with the same object name.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I want to create User Object singleton and access all variables in it. How can I do it?

Comment: If all you are saving is those 4 variables, then use SharedPreferences instead of a User object.

Comment: do you know about the singleton pattern ?

Comment: No, but I can guess it is useful in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a singleton?

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static User instance;

    private String studyProgram;
    private String name;
    private String facebookId;
    private String vuId;

    private User() {}

    public static User getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new User();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a singleton and there is no need to pass it to the intent since it is accessible globally.

In Login.java do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,SecondActivity.class);
User user = User.getInstance();
user.setName(name);
user.setFacebookId(id);
startActivity(intent);
```

In StudyPRogram.java do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
User user = User.getInstance();
user.setVuId(data);
user.setStudyProgram(data1);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity do:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);

    User user = User.getInstance();

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(user.toString());
}
```

Comment: What do you want to say me? This code is not working well.

Comment: This is a Singleton an can be accessed from all Activities but can only be used for one instance.

Comment: OK. how I can use it in my case with a proper manner? Because when I am adding it in User.java class. My app is crashing.

Comment: All the places you use the user object you must start by calling 'User.getInstance()' first than you can use the getters and setters.

Comment: No, it is not showing all values, it is just showing vuId's value and studyProgram's value, name and facebookId both are showing null. So, what should I do?

Comment: So it is working since you get the vuId and studyPrograms value! It seems to be that the name and facebookId are null in Login.java before assigning them to the User singleton. Try to log the name and id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115015/discussion-between-tristan-richard-and-nabia-saroosh).

Comment: Before the use of getInstance(), I have the same problem. Basically in the name and facebookId, I am reading the data from facebook and assign it in name and facebookId.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the User variables and methods static and then access them through the User class rather then creating an instance of the user class.

```
 User.setVuId(data);
```

Rather than instantiating it like

```
User user = new User();
user.setVuId(data);
```

Comment: Yes, I have to write User user = new User(); at the top of this class but I want to access all variables in one object at the same time which i have declared in multiple activities. This is my problem.